# nextJS dynamic routing page structure

Tags: dynamic, routes, next.js

I have a question 
web url I want is 
area/Texas/region/houston or area/Texas/region/dallas 
area and region is static, Texas and houston can change
but I don't know how to make page direction in nextJS
pages
 ㄴ area 
  ㄴ[area].js 
  ㄴregion 
   ㄴ[region].js

this distructure not working because [area] page and region folder in one folder together

Let me know how I make distructure!! 
Help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also [dynamicname] directories, and the index.js inside the directory will be used. So can have something like this.

pages
 ㄴ area
      ㄴ [areaname]
         ㄴindex.js - this one will run in a /area/Texas or /area/California request.    
  
 ㄴregion
            ㄴ[region].js